# Can i make a doPost and then doGet on the same submit button?

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlets, restful-architecture

I have form with a button submit and i want that when the button submit is clicked make a POST through a servlet to  database (mariadb) and then GET the values posted again through the same servlet to a HTML page on the same event (the clicked button).

When a run the servlet it gets the new values posted through the submit button on the HTML..But only when i ran the servlet by itself(on Netbeans right click on the code and run..). It work separately.

> Here it is the doPost method:

```
@Override
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
  Gson convertir = new Gson();

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); // PrintWriter imprime texto en un objeto. getWriter() devuelve un objeto PrintWriter.

    String texto = request.getReader().readLine();//getReader() devuelve el contenido de la respuesta. readLine() lee el contenido de la variable "texto" y lo retorna.

    TreeMap<String, String> objetoSabor = convertir.fromJson(texto, TreeMap.class);// Crea una lista treemap y convierte la respuesta de JSON a treemap..

    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection conMDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cremo", "root", "root");
        PreparedStatement sentencia = conMDB.prepareStatement("insert into inventarios (inv_hel_id, inv_sab_id, inv_cantidad  ) values (?,?,?)");
        sentencia.setString(1, objetoSabor.get("heladerias"));//"nombre" lo saca del objeto "sabor" en AJAX (sabor.nombre)
        sentencia.setString(2, objetoSabor.get("sabor"));//"calorias" lo saca del objeto "calorias" en AJAX (sabor.calorias)
        sentencia.setString(3, objetoSabor.get("calorias"));//"calorias" lo saca del objeto "calorias" en AJAX (sabor.calorias)
        sentencia.execute();
```

> And here the doGet method:

```
@Override
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();


    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection conMDB = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost/cremo", "root", "root");


        PreparedStatement sentencia = conMDB.prepareStatement( "select * from inventarios");


        ResultSet resultado = sentencia.executeQuery();//ResulSet pone el puntero en la primera fila de la tabla de la Base de datos.


        while( resultado.next() ){
          out.println("[OK] "  + request.getParameter("heladerias") + ", " + resultado.getString(2) + ", " + resultado.getString(3));
        }
```

> The html form:

```
<form>
            <fieldset>
                <p>


                    <select id="heladerias" name="heladerias">
                        <option value="1">Palermo</option>
                        <option value="2">Recoleta</option>
                        <option value="3">Belgrano</option>
                    </select>

                    <select id="sabores" name="sabores" >
                        <option value="1">Sambayon italiano</option>
                        <option value="3">Sambayon Frances</option>
                        <option value="5">Mousse de Limon</option>
                        <option value="6">Pistacho</option>
                    </select>

                    <input id="sabor_calorias"   type="number" name="quantity" min="1" max="6000">

                </p>


                <input id="fecha" type="date" name="fecha" step="1" min="2016-01-01" max="2016-12-31">


                <input type="submit"  value="Submit" onclick="envioCorrecto()"/>

            </fieldset>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can send response in doPost method only. No need to write doGet method separately. After inserting the data into DB, write the logic for get data in the doPost method only.